# Laravel - Set collection data from another collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, relationship

I have two tables: `products` and `colors`.

Products

```
id | product_name | color_id
----------------------------
1  | Product 1    | 1
2  | Product 2    | 2
```

Colors

```
id | name
---------
1 | blue
2 | silver
3 | green
```

And i have collection:

`$product = Product::all();`

And i want to have another collection from `color` table with colors which exists in `product` collection. So i want to see colors: blue (product 1) and silver (product 2) without green. Is it possible to get something like this? I think about relationship but i'm not sure how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: `Products::with('color')->whereIn('color_id', [1, 2])->get();`

Comment: @SebastiánPérez yes, but i don't want to use hard-code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want take colors from colors table that are assigned to any product, then you can do like this:

```
$products = Product::all();
$assigned_color_ids = $products->pluck('id')->toArray();
$colors = Color::whereIn('id', $assigned_color_ids)->get();
```

For your given table, the query will be `whereIn('id', [1, 2])` because color with id 3 is not used in products table

Answer (score 0):

maybe can try this,
in your COlors model define a relation to products

```
/**
 * Get the products for the color.
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Products','color_id');
}
```

and you can access to all products from color model,

```
$colorswithproducts = Colors::whereHas('products')->get();

dd($colorswithproducts);

1 => [
    'name' => 'blue'
    'products' =>
    [
        "id" : "1",
        'name' => ....
    ] 
 ]
```